# I took a old webcam from a laptop and connected it over usb, it does not work

Tags: usb, laptop

The camera has 5 pins: 5v, D-, D+, GND and powerC.

I dont know where to plug power c in.

Can someone help me please, the camera is CNF9138_A1 By Chicony

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting old webcam via USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58552/connecting-old-webcam-via-usb)

Answer (score 3):

powerC is input for 3.3V you need to get this from somewhere, you can use a voltage regulator. You can follow the steps in the link which sent by @evildemonic but nowadays thanks to arduino type boards there is a lot of option for tiny voltage regulators, you can check AMS1117 it will work. Just do not give 5V to this pin ever.